# Angularjs custom directive scope:true change it's parent scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to write one custom directive and I put scope:true.As per my knowledge this should take parent scope and when we change in model it should change it's internal scope only. but in this below example I find that when ever I change the directive the parent also get changed. Can anyone please tell me that the reason behind it.

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="mainControll"> <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem harum numquam odio, tenetur earum deleniti culpa recusandae? Temporibus expedita, porro numquam at voluptas aspernatur nemo veniam nam, vel assumenda placeat!</div>{{text}}<br/> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" ng-model="text"> <firstdir></firstdir> </div>
```

**javascript**

```
var app = angular.module("myModule",[]);
app.controller("mainControll",function($scope){
  $scope.text = "Content from controller";
});

app.directive("firstdir",function(){
  return{
    restrict:"EACM",
    replace:"true",
    scope:"true",
    template:'<p>{{text}}<br/><input type="text" class="form-control"   id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "text"></p>'
  }
})
```

the sample you can find [here](http://codepen.io/nabaraj/pen/xVwMLb)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you have provided the scope is assigned with string "true" which should actually be a boolean true

```
app.directive("firstdir",function(){ return{
restrict:"EACM",
replace:"true",
scope: true,
template:'<p>{{text}}<br/><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" ng-model = "text"></p>'}})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it was my mistake. Thank you for your time.

Comment: u r welcome..if this is the answer you are looking for then please flag it as the answer..thanks

Comment: Hi do same for replace. it accept boolean value but not as string.